# Geojson File not aligning with map correctly

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I have a geojson file that I'm trying to add to a map but for some reason, they are misaligned.

I have made this simplified version of the page, removing all my markers and all other HTML to try to isolate the problem but with no joy.

I've tried

- Loading the Geojson on the page in `<script>` tags like the leaflet JS tutorial shows
- Saving the Geojson in a folder on my site and calling it to load with JavaScript
- And with the link, you see below I've used fetch to get the API

http://codeyeti.co.uk/ActiveCommuters/map_dev.php

They all return this same misaligned result.

the Geojson file can be viewed on Maptiler where it displays perfectly

https://cloud.maptiler.com/data/b92719af-8d5b-4006-9631-3d8b13eaa1c6/#9.19/53.2826/-4.3682

here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" crossorigin=""></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>
      <script>
  var map = L.map('map').setView([53.309242,-4.626208], 10);

L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/openstreetmap/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg?key=g9ErshPDnj0LYYtEd10o', {
attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>',
}).addTo(map);

fetch('https://api.maptiler.com/data/b92719af-8d5b-4006-9631-3d8b13eaa1c6/features.json?key=g9ErshPDnj0LYYtEd10o')
    .then(function (responce) {
    return responce.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      L.geoJSON(data).addTo(map);
    });
  </script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Has anyone had trouble like this?

Answer (score 1):

misaligned result by `style.css` line 271 :

```
img {
   margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

you can check it

Map of leaflet is a group images

Comment: You genius! there was no hope I was going to figure that one out. Thanks a million for that much appreciated.

Comment: I spent ages with this same issue. I thought the GeoJson path was misaligned, but actually it was the images in the "leaflet-tile-container". It's worth digging into the dev tools to check this if you have the same issue. I manages to override my CSS with a :not() selector...  


`"img:not( .leaflet-container  img)" : { image styles }`